# jquery validate with if statement in custom method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the validate plugin for jquery and have the following custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
    if (element.prop("required")) {  
        var re = new RegExp('^([FG]?\\d{5}|\\d{5}[AB])$');
    } else  {
        var re = new RegExp('^'+element.defaultValue+'|^([FG]?\\d{5}|\\d{5}[AB])$');
    }
    return re.test(value);
});
```

The if statement returns the error `element.prop is not a function`.

I've also tried $(this).prop... and although I don't get any errors it always runs the else part of the statement.

Is there anything else I can use instead to achieve this??

EDIT:

Here's the call:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    debug: true,
    ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: {
                 depends: function() {
                     return $(this).prop("required");
                 }
            },
            username: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            username: "Enter a valid username"
        }
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label.text("Good result!");
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
if ($(element).prop("required")) {
```

Comment: Ha! As much as I thought I'd tried everything, I guess I missed this one. Thanks!

Comment: That is often the case - you did almost try this exact answer, but not quite :)

Comment: @Tom: If you don't want to wrap the element into a jQuery object you can also use `element.getAttribute("required")`, though if you are using jQuery anyways, then there is no need to mix syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you may be using older jQuery version:

try $(element).attr("required")

Comment: try $(element).attr("required")

Comment: @RajeevSharma: You should update your answer with your comment `$(element).attr("required")` as `element.attr("required")` is not going to execute.